# manually create XML for DataTable to send to WebService in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, datatable

I'm totally stuck with this for hours now.

I'm consuming a webservice. This Webservice only has one method:

```
Execute(string strMethod, string strParametersXML)
```

I've created a Service Reference in Visual Studio for the WebService. 
This WebSerice can be used to call Methods at the server. So for each method you have different Methodname "strMethod" and different "strParametersXML".

One of this Methods asks for a DataTable as a Parameter in strParameterXML. If i create a datatable in C# and pull the XML with dataTableObject.writeXML(<>) to send it as strParameterXML, the Webservice only returns that the XML could not be parsed.

How does one habe to create a dataTable to send it as a XML-String to a WebService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will convert a Data table to Xml string

```
public string ConvertDataTableToXml(DataTable table)
 {
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  table.WriteXml(stream, true);
  str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
  string xmlstr;
  xmlstr = reader.ReadToEnd();
  return (xmlstr);
 }
```

May be this will help you in converting a Data Table to Xml which may be re constructed back in the webservice.

it would be best if you can get WSDL of that particular method

Comment: The WSDL of the webservice lists only the "Execute(strMethod, strParametersXML)". That's my problem. The Methods are then handed over on the server side to an function which checks, if there is a method with the given strMethod name and then trys to cast the given strParametersXML string to objects. If this succeeds, the method on the server is called with the given parameters and the resilt is then sent back to client as answer as XML-String.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish. However, you could try creating a TypedDataSet, create it in visual studio so you get an .xsd and expose and use that?

Comment: I've tried that. Same result. All i get back from webservice is the answer that the xml could not be parsed. (Exception Details -&gt; Error in XML-Document (1,1).). If i call Execute with a method that doesn't need a dataTable (let's say string, Integer, etc.) the webservice returns a valid result.